# Sympy: How to compute Lie derivative of matrix with respect to a vector field

Tags: python, numpy, vector, sympy, derivative

I have a system(x'=f(x)+g(x)u), such that `f(x) is f:R3->R3` and `g(x) is g:R3->R(3x2)`. 
My system is

[image]
[image]

As you can see, it is a MIMO nonlinear control system and I wish to find the controllability matrix for my system. Controllability matrix in this case is formulated by
C=[g [f,g] [f,[f,g]] ..],
where [f,g] denotes the lie bracket operation between f and g.
That is the reason why I need to compute Lie derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector field and vice versa. Because [f,g]=f*dg/dx-g*df/dx

Here in my system, f is 3x1 and g is 3x2 as there are two inputs available.
And I wish to calculate the above matrix C in Python. 
My system is
`f=sm.Matrix([[x1**2],[sin(x1)+x3**2],[cos(x3)+x1**2]])` and
`g=sm.Matrix([[cos(x1),0],[x1**2,x2],[0,0]])`.

My code is:

```
from sympy.diffgeom import *
from sympy import sqrt,sin,cos

M     = Manifold("M",3)
P     = Patch("P",M)

coord          = CoordSystem("coord",P,["x1","x2","x3"])
x1,x2,x3       = coord.coord_functions()
e_x1,e_x2,e_x3 = coord.base_vectors()

f      = x1**2*e_x1 + (sin(x1)+x3**2)*e_x2 + (cos(x3) + x1**2)*e_x3
g      = (cos(x1))*e_x1+(x1**2,x2)*e_x2 + 0*e_x3

#h1    = x1
#h2    = x2
#Lfh1  = LieDerivative(f,h1)
#Lfh2  = LieDerivative(f,h2)
#print(Lfh1)
#print(Lfh2)

Lfg    = LieDerivative(f,g)
print(Lfg)
```

Why isn't my code giving me correct answer?

Comment: What is SO? I don't get it? Actually I need to compute Lfg in order to compute state transformation for my nonlinear system

Comment: I've edited my original question, kindly check it out, in case you want to know the exact question, I'll post it as well.

Comment: SO = StackOver... You need to give  data  and expected output, otherwise SO cant figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try using this for your g: `g = (cos(x1)*e_x1+x1**2*e_x2+0*e_x3, 0*e_x1+x2*e_x2+0*e_x3)` That will get you a little farther. But then you will run into problems with `LieDerivative(f,g)`. It does not seem to work as you expect. Have a look here: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/diffgeom.html

Comment: @Merlin, I have updated my question and also included the exact problem I am working on, kindly have a look. Also I need to formulate controllability matrix that comprises of these lie derivatives.

Comment: @Hannebambel I have already gone through that link that you sent me. In fact whatever code I wrote is based on that link only. I however couldnt find an instance where they took lie derivative of a matrix wrt a vector field. But I am sure diffgeom has that feature. Also, I cant take divergence, I mean it is showing some error.

Comment: I kind of feel like playing with the problem myself. Unfortunately I can not see your system. The codecogs link seems to be broken. Do you mind pasting the original latex? I guess most people here can compile it themselves or even read directly. And the others probably don't understand enough math to help you anyways ;-)

Comment: @Hannebambel
Hi! I have added the png instead of the link of that png, can you see my problem now? It is a simple system comprising of 3 nonlinear but control-affine differential equations. the f is vector field(3x1) and g is also a vector field with dimension(3x2). g is also known as input gain matrix in control theory.

Comment: Actually, the main problem here is not mathematics, I can manually calculate the lie brackets, but I want my computer to do it for me! Also my other system is a gigantic system with 8 differential equations describing the dynamics of an airship-- hence finding lie bracket for this monstrous system by hand will be pain, thats why I badly wanted to know how to code it in python.

Comment: So the problem seems to be how to properly define the vectorfield `g`. Once I use tuples `(a,b)` it does not get recognized as such anymore. But this really beyond my sympy knowledge. Maybe you should ask a new question on how to define your `g` as a vectorfield in sympy.

Comment: Is there any numpy or scpiy version of lie derivative? It would very much solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The only error in your code is due to the tuple used for multiple inputs. For LieDerivative in Sympy.diffgeom to work you need a vector field defined properly.

For single input systems, the exact code that you have works without the tuple, so, in that case, for example if you have 
`g = (cos(x1))*e_x1+x1**2*e_x2 + 0*e_x3`

(that is g(x) is 3 x 1 matrix with just the first column). Then, making the above change, you get the correct Lie derivatives.

For multiple input case, (as in your question), you can simply separate the two columns into g1 and g2 and proceed as the above case. This works because for multiple inputs case,
[See math here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPX0u.png)

where g_1 and g_2 are the two columns. The final result for Lgh is a 1 x 2 matrix which you can basically get if you have the two results calculated above (Lg1h and Lg2h).

Code -

```
from sympy.diffgeom import *
from sympy import sqrt,sin,cos
from sympy import *
M = Manifold("M",3)
P = Patch("P",M)

coord          = CoordSystem("coord",P,["x1","x2","x3"])
x1,x2,x3       = coord.coord_functions()
e_x1,e_x2,e_x3 = coord.base_vectors()

f  = x1**2*e_x1 + (sin(x1)+x3**2)*e_x2 + (cos(x3) + x1**2)*e_x3
g1 = (cos(x1))*e_x1+(x1**2)*e_x2 + 0*e_x3
g2 = 0*e_x1+ x2*e_x2 + 0*e_x3
h = x1

Lg1h = LieDerivative(g1,h)
Lg2h = LieDerivative(g2,h)
Lgh = [Lg1h, Lg2h]
print(Lgh)
```